# Trying to build Encoder Decoder with Attention Mechanism, but graph results always disconnected, pls could you help me?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nltk, chatbot, attention-model

```
dimensionality = 4

#trainint encoder
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))

encoder = Bidirectional(LSTM(dimensionality, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, 
                             go_backwards=True), merge_mode='sum')
encoder_outputs, for_h, for_c, bac_h, bac_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
encoder_states = [tf.add(for_h, for_c), tf.add(bac_h, bac_h) ]

#training decoder
decoder = LSTM(dimensionality, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder(decoder_inputs, initial_state= encoder_states)

dot_prod = dot([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs], axes=[2, 2])
attention = Activation('softmax', name='attention')
attention_vec = attention(dot_prod)

context = dot([attention_vec, encoder_outputs], axes=[2, 1])
decoder_comb = concatenate([context, decoder_outputs], name='decoder_comb')

dense = Dense(num_decoder_tokens, activation='softmax')
output = dense(decoder_comb)


training_model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], output)
```

Here you can find summary:

```
    Model: "functional_12"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_13 (InputLayer)           [(None, None, 1780)] 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_2 (Bidirectional) [(None, None, 4), (N 57120       input_13[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_14 (InputLayer)           [(None, None, 2257)] 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Add_4 (TensorFlowOp [(None, 4)]          0           bidirectional_2[0][1]            
                                                                 bidirectional_2[0][2]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Add_5 (TensorFlowOp [(None, 4)]          0           bidirectional_2[0][3]            
                                                                 bidirectional_2[0][3]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                   [(None, None, 4), (N 36192       input_14[0][0]                   
                                                                 tf_op_layer_Add_4[0][0]          
                                                                 tf_op_layer_Add_5[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dot_12 (Dot)                    (None, None, None)   0           lstm_5[0][0]                     
                                                                 bidirectional_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
attention (Activation)          (None, None, None)   0           dot_12[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dot_13 (Dot)                    (None, None, 4)      0           attention[0][0]                  
                                                                 bidirectional_2[0][0]            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
decoder_comb (Concatenate)      (None, None, 8)      0           dot_13[0][0]                     
                                                                 lstm_5[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, None, 2257)   20313       decoder_comb[0][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 113,625
Trainable params: 113,625
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

And finally below I paste my attempt to separate encoder and decoder in order to do inference, but it raises an error. I tried to use training_model layers/output/input whenever I could but there is still something that I am missing.

```
 #inference encoder
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

#inference decoder
decoder_s_h = Input(shape=(dimensionality, ))
decoder_s_c = Input(shape=(dimensionality, ))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_s_h, decoder_s_c]
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder(decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

dot_prod = dot([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs], axes=[2, 2])
attention_vec = attention(dot_prod)

context = dot([attention_vec, encoder_outputs], axes=[2, 1])

decoder_comb = concatenate([context, decoder_outputs])

output= dense(decoder_comb)

decoder_model = Model([decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs, [output] + decoder_states)
```

I tried so many times to change this configuration but I can't resolve graph disconnection. Could you help me?
PS. I am new to NLP so pls be kind with me, I am a student still not a deep learning specialist...
Thank you so much for your time and help!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-89f9761124cf> in <module>()
     18 output= dense(decoder_comb)
     19 
---> 20 decoder_model = Model([decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs, [output] + decoder_states)
     21 
     22 #encoder decoder model

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
    929                              'The following previous layers '
    930                              'were accessed without issue: ' +
--> 931                              str(layers_with_complete_input))
    932         for x in nest.flatten(node.outputs):
    933           computable_tensors.add(id(x))

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_13:0", shape=(None, None, 1780), dtype=float32) at layer "bidirectional_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: ['lstm_5']
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `input`, `output` properties when creating models with functional api.

Try to change by something like that:

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_encoder_tokens))
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, num_decoder_tokens))
encoder_outputs, for_hidden, for_cell, bac_hidden, bac_cell = training_model(encoder_input, decoder_inputs)
```

Another error relates to this line:

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
```

where encoder_states is not dependent from encoder_input. So tensorflow is not able to build graph.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, I edited my question with new coding. I wrote it following your suggestions, but another error occurs again. I think that something is going bad mapping variables. Could you help me?